# No suitable application records were found.Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Toast' is correct

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been struggling to get Archive->Validate to work with Toast. Only this framework has issues out of all our project decencies.

When I validate my archive to push it to the AppStore, I get following error:
[image: "No suitable application records were found.Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Toast' is correct".]

I have been trying to solve this issue for the 2 past days with no luck. I have followed all suggestions on the internet. Could you please help us to address this issue?

I'm on xCode version 9.1 and pods version 1.3.1

Comment: Have you created your project over itunesconnect with same bundle identifier ?

Comment: I don't think you want your bundle id to be `org.cocoapods.Toast` - It should be the bundle id in your domain

Comment: No, I have created project over the  itunesconnect with my project bundle identifier (com.company_Name.project_Name), But this error is showing due to org.cocoapods.Toast.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?